# Second day, no training, alone in office

Tags: offices

I got a job in a office without even a title for the position that I’m responsible for. I distribute, and organize work orders to contractors. This is my second day and I have a barely idea of what to do. There are not others on the office but myself. I only have my boss phone number and of course the contractor numbers. Every contractor has a unique preference and requirements to do certain task which I barely know. Of course there are more things, and my boss ask me to do task that I have never done. Any tips of how I can nail this job?

Comment: Use the time to find a new job while your paid for your trial period?

Comment: I was thinking the same!

Comment: 2 days is pretty short. Do you know if your employer has plans to train you, or onboard you? Have you asked?

Comment: They trained me ... yesterday. He told me that I was going to be trained, but I think that was it. But for me it was more like “showed me” than training me.

Comment: If they haven't given you a title, call the HR people and ask them. If they don't have a title for you, take one; call yourself the Contracts Director (or Manager, or similar).

Comment: Sounds great, are you guys hiring?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

talk to the contractors, explain that you are new, ask about their preferences, and be very much aware of the fact that they are going to try to take advantage of you.

Verify things through your boss.  If you get the same info from the contractors and boss,  you know that those contractors are honest, if you get different information in favor of the contractors, you know that they are ones you are going to need to watch carefully.

Create relationships with the contractors, engage in small talk, and get to know them.  It's harder (for most) to cheat people with whom they have an established relationship.  Also, having a good relationship with a contractor puts you in a stronger position when negotiating, and will make it more likely for you to get a benefit of the doubt.

For example, if there's a problem, and you have a relationship with the contractor, that contractor is going to be much more likely to discuss it with you rather than escalate it to your boss.

Comment: Wow, that helps a lot. Thank you.

Comment: @BryanEnid I have been in your situation.  GOOD LUCK!

Comment: Best answer. And be prepared to eat (and pay for) a lot of dinners and lunches with these contractors. It pays off in the end.